# I'm attempting to create a vertical menu with flyouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've spent all night attempting to create this. I finally got it to where it will display a flyout, but all of the dimensions are wrong, and I'm obviously not understanding the hierarchy of css here. My end goal is for it to look like this. (Vertical, color scheme, pretty icons) [What I want it to look like.](http://jsfiddle.net/NGZ2g/) But I want it to act like [this.](http://webpulse.com.br/flexmenu/vertical-left.html)

**HTML**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".menu").menu({speed: 400,type: "vertical",});});</script>    

<body>
<div class="content">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="JavaScript:void(0)"><i class="icon-dashboard">     
</i>Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)"><i class="icon-servers"></i>Servers</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">View Virtual Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Add Virtual Servers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)"><i class"icon-user"></i>Users</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
 @import "./font-awesome.css";
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
.menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Segoe UI, Arial;
    list-style: none;
    background: #303641;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
.menu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative
    float: left;
    height: 2.5em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
    color: #aaabae;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-indent: -500em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
    -webkit-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    -o-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear
}
.menu li:hover>a, .menu li.active a {
    background: #2b303a;
    color: #fff
}
.menu li.right {
    float: right
}
.menu ul, .menu ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 4em;
    background: #303641;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
.menu ul {
    top: 60px;
    left: 0
}
.menu ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}
.menu ul li {
    clear: both;
    width: 4em;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px
}
.menu ul li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 4em;
    color: #dedede;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    -o-transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear;
    transition: color .2s linear, background .2s linear
}
menu>li.showhide {
    display: none;
    width: 4em;
    height: 2.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #dedede;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background: #303641;
}
menu>li.showhide span.title {
    margin: 16px 0 0 25px;
    float: left
}
.menu>li.showhide span.icon {
    margin: 17px 20px;
    float: right
}
.menu>li.showhide .icon em {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ccc
}
.menu.vertical {
    width: 4em;
}
.menu.vertical li {
    width: 4em;
}
.menu.vertical li a {
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: 4em;
    padding: 18px 20px 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
.menu.vertical ul li {
    width: 4em;
}
.menu.vertical ul, .menu.vertical ul li ul {
    width: 4em;
}
.menu.vertical ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}
.menu.vertical ul li ul {
    top: 1px
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
 $.fn.menu=function(e){function r(){$(".menu").find("li").unbind();$(".menu").find("ul").hide(0);if(window.innerWidth<=768){o();s();if(n==true){a();n=false}}else{u();i();if(t.type=="horizontal"&&t.align=="right"&&n==false){a();n=true}}}function i(){$(".menu li").bind("mouseover",function(){$(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).fadeIn(t.speed)}).bind("mouseleave",function(){$(this).children("ul").stop(true,true).fadeOut(t.speed)})}function s(){$(".menu > li").bind("click",function(){if($(this).children("ul").css("display")=="none"){$(this).find("ul").slideDown(t.interval)}else{$(this).children("ul").slideUp(t.interval)}})}function o(){$(".menu > li:not(.showhide)").hide(0);$("-menu > li.showhide").show(0);$(".menu > li.showhide").bind("click",function(){if($(".menu > li").is(":hidden")){$(".menu > li").slideDown(300)}else{$(".menu > li:not(.showhide)").slideUp(300);$(".menu > li.showhide").show(0)}})}function u(){$(".menu > li").show(0);$(".menu > li.showhide").hide(0)}function a(){$(".menu > li").addClass("right");var e=$(".menu").width();var t=$(".menu").children("li");var n=0;$(".menu").children("li:not(.showhide)").detach();for(var r=t.length;r>=1;r--){$(".menu").append(t[r])}}var t={speed:300,type:"horizontal",align:"left"};$.extend(t,e);var n=false;if(t.type=="vertical"){$(".menu").addClass("vertical");if(t.align=="right"){$(".menu").addClass("right")}}$(".menu").prepend("<li class='showhide'><span class='title'>MENU</span><span class='icon'><em></em><em></em><em></em><em></em></span></li>");r();$(window).resize(function(){r()})}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you provide! I appreciate anything :)

Comment: use position absolute for the flyouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things need to be reset.

1. Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `ul.menu`. Otherwise your flyouts will be... hidden. :)
2. Set the `.menu>li` to `position: relative` and then the sub `ul`s to `position: absolute` offsetting however you need to.
3. Make sure you're targeting specific `<a>` elements with your initial css by using child selectors instead of decendant selectors. That is, use `.menu > li > a` vs `.menu li a`. The former will only target `a`s that are children of the `li`s that are children of `.menu`. The latter will target all `a`s that are descendant of all `li`s that are descendants of `.menu` which will include your flyout's `<a>`s.

**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGZ2g/2/)** should get your started.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!
1) Virtual Pencils made me giggle.
2) Thank you for your detailed response. It helped a lot.